# How to make my program perform multiple functions simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that works perfectly if I use it in the main `while` loop.
But if I try to call it on a `thread.start()`, it will not read the `sleep.time` functions, it will try to do everything too fast and doesn't work good.

```
    if matchHp2 != healthPixel and doHeal == 'yes':
        time.sleep(.6)
        pyautogui.press(healHk2)
        time.sleep(.6)
```

This piece of code will work fine if I only have in the main `while` loop, but if I call a new thread in the main `while` loop it doesn't read the `time.wait`, etc..

here is my full code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time
from threading import Thread

healHk = 'F2'
healHk2 = 'F1'
manaHk = 'F3'
hasteHk = 'F7'
doHeal = 'yes'
doMana = 'yes'
doHaste = 'yes'
spellHk1 = 'F4'
spellHk2 = 'F5'
time.sleep(2)


def healer():
    manaPixel = (83, 80, 218)
    healthPixel = (241, 97, 97)
    hastePixel = (249, 249, 248)
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    matchMana = im.getpixel((1175, 160))
    matchHp = im.getpixel((1204, 148))
    matchHp2 = im.getpixel((1163, 148))
    matchHaste = im.getpixel((597, 63))
    if matchHp2 != healthPixel and doHeal == 'yes':
        time.sleep(.6)
        pyautogui.press(healHk2)
        time.sleep(.6)
    if matchMana != manaPixel and doMana == 'yes':
        pyautogui.press(manaHk)
        time.sleep(.6)
    if matchHp != healthPixel and matchHp2 == healthPixel and doHeal == 'yes':
        time.sleep(.6)
        pyautogui.press(healHk)
        time.sleep(.6)
    if matchHaste != hastePixel and doHaste == 'yes':
        time.sleep(.6)
        pyautogui.press(hasteHk)
        time.sleep(1)


def attacker():
    greenFollow = (92, 255, 92)
    monsterPixel = (187, 214, 40)
    monsterLoc = (10, 49)
    attackBorder = (255, 0, 0)
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    matchFollow = im.getpixel((1262, 202))
    matchMonster = im.getpixel(monsterLoc)
    matchAttackRight = im.getpixel((23, 48))
    if matchFollow != greenFollow:
        time.sleep(.6)
        pyautogui.leftClick(1262, 204)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.moveTo(1090, 204, duration=.3)
    if matchMonster == monsterPixel and matchAttackRight != attackBorder:
        pyautogui.press('space')
        time.sleep(.6)
    if matchAttackRight == attackBorder:
        time.sleep(.6)
        pyautogui.press(spellHk1)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press(spellHk2)
        time.sleep(1)


while True:
    x = Thread(target=healer)
    x.start()

    attacker()

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I need my macro to perform multiple tasks at once, hence why i wanted to open a function on a new thread and another one just by calling it inside the main Loop so they could run simultaneously, but my problem is that when i start a thread for a function it doesnt perform the same as if i only called the function itself, it spams hotkeys, takes longer to read pixels on screen, etc.. can someone help? thank you all

Comment: Can you update your code to include the thread setup?

Comment: Just did thank you!